# How to get size of directory with ~1.6 million files in it

Tags: files, filesystems, directory, disk-usage

I have a folder which contains around 220 folders with 5-10k items, totaling around 1.6 million. I've tried using df, but I have terabytes of other data on the same drive so it doesn't give me a useful number. When I run `du -sh`, I get `du: cannot access '(redacted filepath)': Too many open files` after a little bit. Is there any reasonable way to alleviate my issue with du, or an alternative command that works better with millions of files?

I should add I don't really care about how long the command takes to run, as long as it happens some time before the heat death of the universe.

Comment: What implementation and version of du are you using? On what OS? Also, what's the output of `ulimit -n`?

Comment: Pragmatically, I would run du -s --block-size=1K on each of the 220 folders, and aggregate the 220 lines of result in awk, converting to -h format after the summation. You could even try some parallelism in there, too, to save the universe some time. However, `du` tracks hard links to avoid double-counting, so hard links across two or more of the 220 folders will be counted multiple times.